# Error in Resample

Tags: raster, r, resampling

I am currently working on a Project that I thought I had finished. After closing everything down and re-running the code to check that everything was in order I encountered an error message on a "Resample" operation. I was trying to resample two layers with different extents but the same CRS:

```
> overlayBRD@extent
class      : Extent 
xmin       : 5 
xmax       : 16 
ymin       : 47 
ymax       : 56* 

> overlayKR@extent
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -293508 
xmax       : 822492 
ymin       : 1914749 
ymax       : 2929749 

> overlayKR@crs
CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 

> overlayBRD@crs
CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs*
```

Previously this has worked without any problems what so ever. however when using :

```
> s <- resample(overlayKR, overlayBRD, method="ngb")
```

i rechieve the error message :

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  Fehler bei der Auswertung des Argumentes 'i' bei der Methodenauswahl für Funktion '[': invalid 'size' argument*
```

Does anyone know where this Issue stems from or what i can do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in `overlayKR` extent are very large...

```
> overlayKR@extent
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -293508 
xmax       : 822492 
ymin       : 1914749 
ymax       : 2929749
```

but the CRS says these are lat-long degrees:

```
> overlayKR@crs
CRS arguments: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

which is clearly not true.

`overlayBRD` looks plausible, because its extents are all small enough to be degrees.

So it looks like, if this worked previously, you've missed a processing step with `overlayKR`.